# Better way to modify multiple ranges (basic addition and subtraction) using arrays or similar?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is the following code-snippet I'm using in my Google Spreadsheet `onEdit()` function:

```
else if(editedCell.getColumn() == 13 && editedCell.getRow() == 29) {
    var modVal = sheet.getRange("L29").getValue();

    if(editedCell.getValue() == "Yes") {
      sheet.getRange("G23").setValue(sheet.getRange("G23").getValue() + modVal);
      sheet.getRange("G24").setValue(sheet.getRange("G24").getValue() + modVal);
      sheet.getRange("G25").setValue(sheet.getRange("G25").getValue() + modVal);
      sheet.getRange("G26").setValue(sheet.getRange("G26").getValue() + modVal);
      sheet.getRange("G27").setValue(sheet.getRange("G27").getValue() + modVal);
      sheet.getRange("G28").setValue(sheet.getRange("G28").getValue() + modVal);
      sheet.getRange("G29").setValue(sheet.getRange("G29").getValue() + modVal);
    }
    else if(editedCell.getValue() == "No") {
      sheet.getRange("G23").setValue(sheet.getRange("G23").getValue() - modVal);
      sheet.getRange("G24").setValue(sheet.getRange("G24").getValue() - modVal);
      sheet.getRange("G25").setValue(sheet.getRange("G25").getValue() - modVal);
      sheet.getRange("G26").setValue(sheet.getRange("G26").getValue() - modVal);
      sheet.getRange("G27").setValue(sheet.getRange("G27").getValue() - modVal);
      sheet.getRange("G28").setValue(sheet.getRange("G28").getValue() - modVal);
      sheet.getRange("G29").setValue(sheet.getRange("G29").getValue() - modVal);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm just simply doing each cell manually line by line. Is there a way to specify an array of ranges and then do the math in a simple `foreach()` type function? I'm not sure how to ask my question, but I believe it's self-apparent when looking at my code above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var modVal = sheet.getRange("L29").getValue();

// Create a function that updates a given sheet at a given range with
// the result of a value function
var changeRangeValue = new function(sheet, range, value) {
    sheet.getRange(range).setValue(value(sheet, range));
};

var calculateValue;

if(editedCell.getValue() == "Yes") {
    // Create a function that returns a value of a given sheet at a given range with
    // the mod value added
    calculateValue = new function(sheet, range) {
        return sheet.getRange(range).getValue() + modValue; 
    };
}
else if(editedCell.getValue() == "No") {
    // Create a function that returns a value of a given sheet at a given range with
    // the mod value added        
    calculateValue = new function(sheet, range) {
        return sheet.getRange(range).getValue() - modValue;
    };
}
else {
    // Create a function that returns the current value of a given sheet at a given range
    calculateValue = new function(sheet, range) {
        return sheet.getRange(range).getValue();
    };
}

// Go through G23-G29 and update the range value with the correct value
for(var i=23; i <= 29; i++) {
    changeRangeValue(sheet, "G"+i, calculateValue);
}
```